# Fullcalendar doesn't show correctly event in month mode

Tags: fullcalendar

I have a problem with the fullcalendar, I have an event that occurs on day 3 and day 4, when a event ends before 9am, the month mode is shown only one day, look:

**Week:** (ending before 9am)

[image]

**Month:**

[image]

**Week:** (ending after 9am)

[image]

**Month:**

[image]

How I fix it? I want to show the event in the Month on both days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the nextDayThreshold properties to another hour for the event to display according to your needs.

From the docs:

> When an event's end time spans into another day, the minimum time it must be in order for it to render as if it were on that day.
>
> Duration, default: "09:00:00" (9am)
>
> Only affects timed events that appear on whole-days. Whole-day cells
>   occur in month view, basicDay, basicWeek and the all-day slots in the
>   agenda views.

Example (docs)

```
{ start: '2014-02-04T20:00:00', end: '2014-02-05T02:00:00' }
// goes from 8pm to 2am the next day
```

More info at:
http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/nextDayThreshold/